# How do I smooth my slider value in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script which updates the slider value based on `slowMotionTimeLeft`, to decrease`slowMotionTimeLeft`. I am using a for loop with a coroutine which has a delay of 1 second, like this:

```
IEnumerator DecreaseSlowMotionTime()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5f; i++)
    {
        slowMotionTimeLeft -= 1f; // decrease slow motion

        ///<summary>
        /// if slow motion time is less than or equal to 0 break the loop
        /// </summary>
        if (slowMotionTimeLeft <= 0f)
        {
            onSlowMotion = false; 
            break;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1f); // delay
    }   
}
```

now I have a slider, I want to smoothly update that value based on `slowMotiontimeLeft`, but it is not smooth, it is updating every second like the coroutine, I tried to lerp the values but it does not work.
Here is the script:

```
// Slow Motion Bar
[Header("Slow Motion Slider Bar")]
[SerializeField] private Slider slowMoLeft;
[SerializeField] private float slowSliderSmoothSpeed = 0.125f;

// Other
private Player playerScript;

void Awake()
{
    playerScript = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
}

void Update()
{
    UpdateSlowMoSlider();
}

public void UpdateSlowMoSlider()
{
    slowMoLeft.value = playerScript.slowMotionTimeLeft;
}
```

any tips of what can I do? do I need to update the coroutine timer to make wait 0.1 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it in Update:

```cs
// Remove the IEnumerator DecreaseSlowMotionTime(), instead add this, or if you already use Update() add the content of this method to Update()
public void Update()
{
    if (slowMotionTimeLeft > 0)
    {
        slowMotionTimeLeft -= 1f * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

```cs
// Slow Motion Bar
[Header("Slow Motion Slider Bar")]
[SerializeField] private Slider slowMoLeft;
[SerializeField] private float slowSliderSmoothSpeed = 0.125f;

// Other
private Player playerScript;

void Awake()
{
    playerScript = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
}

void Update()
{
    
    slowMoLeft.value = playerScript.slowMotionTimeLeft;
}
```

Comment: `Using IEnumerators for smooth appearing movement is not recommended.` ... what? ^^ OP was probably going for a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) which in Unity uses `IEnumerator` and is besides doing stuff in `Update` THE way of doing smooth animations ;) The mistake was just the way how it was implemented/used

Comment: @derHugo Seriously? What are the benefits of IEnumerator over Update?

Comment: @derHugo Regardless, I believe you so I updated my statement on that topic.

Comment: And for that matter, what is the benefit of a IEnumerator over Task? I tend to use Update when I want to change things per frame, so mostly appearance, because why update a visual multiple times between frames, FixedUpdate when I want Physics/Physics2D to be accurate and an async Task when I want to change something any other way.

Comment: As said you can find the answers [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) .. a Coroutine is basically a small temporary `Update` method .. that has a start and an end .. for many cases `Update` is more difficult to maintain and less efficient since it basically runs all the time while a Coroutine only when you start it. And then there are some special cases where you don't wait for the next frame but e.g. for a camera to render or the next fixed update ;)

Comment: `what is the benefit of a IEnumerator over Task` .. well a Coroutine still runs **synchronous** and gets one `MoveNext` call per frame ... a `Task` may use anything (most of things) from the Unity API main thread so you'll have to manually make sure that any API calls are dispatched back into the main thread ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code better:

Instead of updating your `slowMotionTimeLeft` once every second, you can do something like this:

```
IEnumerator DecreaseSlowMotionTime()
{
    while (onSlowMotion)
    {
        // decrease slow motion without considering Time.timeScale
        slowMotionTimeLeft -= Time.unscaledDeltaTime; 

        // if slow motion time is less than or equal to 0 break the loop
        if (slowMotionTimeLeft <= 0f)
        {
            onSlowMotion = false; 
        }

        // will execute again in the next frame
        yield return null; 
    }   
}
```

Then your slider will reduce smoothly and at a 1:1 time speed.

Comment: Great solution using IEnumerator!

Answer (score 0):

I know a another way
Just download DoTweenModuleUI and you are good to go
https://github.com/fisheraf/Stroids/blob/master/Stroids/Assets/Demigiant/DOTween/Modules/DOTweenModuleUI.cs

just save this script in any external plugins folder and use

yourimageName.DoFillAmout(TargetValue,Duration);   That's it
Something like this imageSlider.DOFillAmount(perSecElixir / 10, 0.5f);